# Can't show image from database in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

index.html

`<img src="{{beat.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{beat.name}}">`

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'beat/media')
```

models.py

`image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)`

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test', views.test, name='test'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

beat.image.url not working

Comment: Please  grab image url from rendered page (via Inspect feature), open it in new tab. What is the response status? 404, 403, 500? And show project folder structure with path to any media file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have passed queryset in the template. If that's the case, you need to access that with for loop in templates like this:

```
{% for content in beat %}
<img src="{{content.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{content.name}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Please post the views.py so that we can look further to solve the issue.

Edit your urls.py first:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    # Other routes here
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: actually, i have a for loop before it the problem must be from something else since I can print beat.image

Comment: Post the views.py so that it will be easier to debug the issue